# How get the lastest inserted values with JPA?

Tags: database, jpa, jpa-2.0

I need to the get lastest inserted 'product' in my database.
I'm using JPA (EclipseLink) to do that, something like :

```
public List<Product> search(String name){
  // return the lastest results with the maximum of 100 values
}
```

How can I do that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the products with the given name, order the results by insertion date (a column that must be present in the Product entity) of by ID (if using a sequence number as ID), in descending order, and call `setMaxResults(100)` on the query to limit it to 100 results:

```
TypedQuery<Product> q = 
    em.createQuery("select p from Product p"
                   + " where p.name = :name"
                   + " order by p.insertionDate desc", Product.class);
q.setParameter("name", name);
q.setMaxResults(100);
return q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Product` class has a "id" field that is auto incrementing you can do this. Or if the class has a `createDate` field, you could order by that as well.

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Product.class);
q.setOrdering("id desc");
//q.setOrdering("createDate desc"); //If you have a createDate field
q.setRange(0, 100);

try {
    products = (List<Product>)q.execute();
}
finally {
    q.closeAll();
}
```

Comment: Although the solution is right, the code snippet looks like JDO, and not JPA code.

Comment: Haha, yea, it is JDO. Didn't even notice. Your solution is correct too, and is JPA. :)